# OpenLayers MinZoomLevel

Tags: maps, openlayers, zooming

I want to set the MinZoomLevel for a OpenLayers-map with a Zoomify layer. But it doesn't work.  It has no effects whether I put it to the map-options or to the layer options. Further it seems to me, that it only works with FixedZoomLayers but I need it with a zoomify-layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it at
netzwolf.info/kartografie/openlayers/restrictedzoom2.htm

There is a patch to restrict the zoom between a min/max-level and a "hack" for the correct panZoomBar. But it seems that last one doesn't fits for release 2.12.

I've changed it a bit: http://pastebin.com/yuVT0tEF

And here is the Patch: http://pastebin.com/wh9rE3Pv